# "Thickness" of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: geometry, lebesgue-measure

I am looking for the property stating that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has some "thickness" everywhere, i.e. that it does not contain any isolated point nor piece of curve.

For example, a closed disk $\{ \boldsymbol{x} : \left\|\boldsymbol{x}\right\|\leq r\}$ or open disk $\{ \boldsymbol{x} : \left\|\boldsymbol{x}\right\|< r\}$ have some "thickness" everywhere. On the contrary, the union of a disk of center and a line segment with and endpoint outside the disk, e.g.
$$\{\boldsymbol{x} : \left\|\boldsymbol{x}\right\|<r\} \cup \{\alpha \boldsymbol{p}: \alpha \in[0,1]\} $$
with $\boldsymbol{p}=(0,2r)$, has a subset with "zero thickness" (the part of the line segment going out of the disk).

I guess I could state something like this : a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is "thick" everywhere if the neighborhood of any of its point is homeomorphic to a disk. What is this property called? (I came across stuff involving Lebesgue measure, Hausdorff measure, but not sure if it is related)

Comment: Sounds like an open set to me.  A set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is open if for every $x\in S$ there is an open disk $U$ such that $x\in U \subset S$  This is the basic notion in topology.

Comment: Note that closed sets don't really have the property that you want. Boundary points are problematic. As saulspatz said, it's really open sets that you want, but perhaps you could extend it to subsets $S$ such that there exists open $U$ such that $U\subseteq S \subseteq \overline U$, where $\overline U$ stands for closure. What that does is just add some points from the boundary of $U$ and those points shouldn't spoil "thickness".

Comment: The property that you wrote: every point has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to an open disk (I added the open part) is called locally Euclidean space. It's an important part of definition of topological manifold.

Comment: Thanks ! It helps a lot